# In boolean algebra, can the property "ab + a'c = (a + c)(a' + b)" be considered consensus?

Tags: boolean-algebra

It has a form akin to the following:

- (a + t₁)(a' + t₂)(t₁ + t₂) = (a + t₁)(a' + t₂)
- at₁ + a't₂ +t₁t₂ = at₁ + a't₂

These are formally defined as "consensus", will it be accurate to describe the property mentioned in the title consensus as well?

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange!  What do you get if you expand the right side of the formula in the question?

Comment: @MattGroff you get the following: ab + a'c + bc

Comment: So if you set this equal to the left side of the equation in the title, do you see one of the forms you list?

Comment: Oh my god! I see it know, thank you so much @MattGroff

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help!